# How to monitor a web socket connection?

Tags: sockets, monitoring

I tried to find a tool to monitor single web socket connection... I didn't find any useful resources. My intention is to read the data that is going through a socket like, what data is passed through these methods.

- subscribe()
- unsubscribe()
- onreceive()
- send()
- connect()

Comment: If you [minotor](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Minotaur) the web socket connection, then Theseus will kill it.

Comment: Does it mean that "its not possible" ?

Comment: @Benoit: I read that article, it was a-maze-ing.

Comment: no, it is a joke on your typo (minotor instead of monitor)

Answer (score 4):

just saw this question. Answering for any others that may be wondering on the issue.

As mentioned Wireshark can "inspect" WebSocket frames as described [here](http://www.notshabby.net/2012/09/wireshark-dissecting-websocket-conversations/).
However for around an year now, Google Chrome has built in support for this. In Developer Tools, under **Network** there is a sub-filter for **WebSockets**. Another nice Chrome feature are the so-called "[Net-Internals](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/view-net-internals)" thay can really help dive "behind the scenes" in the browser.

Here are some nice articles on how this can all be used together:

1. [Logging WebSocket Frames using Chrome Developer Tools, Net-internals and Wireshark (TOTD #184)](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/logging_websocket_frames_using_chrome)
2. And a [book chapter listed by Springer (PDF)](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm:978-1-4302-4741-8/1.pdf) The book seems to be [The Definitive Guide to HTML5 WebSocket](http://www.springer.com/computer/book/978-1-4302-4740-1).

Comment: The key is, you have to navigate to the "frames" tab, next to the "Headers" tab.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be what you're after, but you could use something like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org).  It'll let you monitor all of the network traffic that's going on from your machine.  From what I can remember, you could then apply filters to only listen for particular types of traffic, or for traffic between certain IP addresses.  I'm not sure if you can apply filters to particular sockets, however it is a pretty flexible piece of software.

If you're looking for a much higher level, then you might be able to get away with just using a something like [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), which is a local proxy server that lets you examine web traffic.

Comment: fiddler doesn't help, infact any http proxy type monitoring tool doesn't show web socket traffic. I will try wireshark and see.Thanks